# Get HashCode from object

Tags: c#, hash

Which method `GetHashCode()` is to prefer?

- Concating all properties and `GetHashCode()` of the result
- `GetHashCode()` for each property and adding each

Code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }
    public List<string> FooList  { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() // 1st way
    {
        return FooId.GetHashCode() + FooName.GetHashCode() + FooList.GetHashCode() ;
    }


    public override int GetHashCode() // 2nd way
    {
        return  string.Concat(FooId, FooName, string.Concat(FooList)).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to compare all properties in the hashcode, when you have an Id field? Isn't that unique?

Comment: Neither is a good solution.  If you do a search for how to combine hash codes, you'll find numerous far superior options.

Comment: @ChoockY no I need to check if the object was modified (same ID) by comparing hashcodes instead of all properties

Comment: *"comparing hashcodes instead of all properties"* -> Be aware that hashcodes are not guaranteed to be different for different values! Hashcodes are only guaranteed to be the same for equal values, but 2 different values may still produce the same hashcode. So you should not rely only on hashcodes for equality comparison.

Comment: _Hashcodes are only guaranteed to be the same for equal values_ sure?

Comment: You should not use hash codes for equality testing, since two different values can hash to the same value.

Comment: Comparing only the hashcodes isn't enough. The hashcode is used to find a "bucket" in which an element is expected to exist. Elements in different buckets cannot be the same, but elements in the same bucket can be different. In this cases the Equals method determines the equality. I think you should just check the Id in hashcode and check all properties in the equals (AND relation).

Comment: @Toshi Absolutely sure, the MSDN documentation of [String.GetHashCode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) for example says the following: *"If two string objects are equal, the GetHashCode method returns identical values. However, there is not a unique hash code value for each unique string value. Different strings can return the same hash code."*

Comment: @bassfader [Object.GetHashCode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) has even better documentation in its notes to inheritors section *"If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value. However, if two objects do not compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two objects do not have to return different values."*